# error "mathtools.sty not found" in ubuntu although it is there in the folder

Tags: mathtools

I found that the file mathtools.sty is present in the folder:

usr->local->texlive->2018->texmf-dist->tex->latex->mathtools

But when I am trying to use the mathtools package on Texmaker, it gives me error that "mathtools.sty not found".

How do I resolve this error using Terminal?

Comment: We need to know more about your system. (1) can latex find this on the command line? `kpsewhich mathtools.sty`, (2) when you get this error in TeXMaker, what is the path to the class your ducument is using (assuming you are using say `article.cls`). My guess: You have two LaTeX installations, the upsteam TeXLive 2018 plus the Ubuntu TeXLive. You made the PATH change in `.bashrc` and you are starting TeXMaker using a menu or by double clicking on a `.tex` file. That will not work. TeXMaker never sees the changes made in bash. It may work if you start texmaker from the command line.

Comment: ... If texmaker works from the command line, then copy the PATH changing linie from `.bashrc` to `.profile`, log put and in again, and see if this helps. If this is the problem, then we have seen it many times before.

Comment: @daleif You are right. kpsewhich mathtools.sty does not detect the file. I opened texmaker from command line, and tried to use mathtools, but it does not work.

Comment: The .tex file that I am editing is in my Documents folder. As I am relatively new to Ubuntu, I am not sure how to make changes that you suggested i.e. the path changing lines from .bashhrc to .profile.

Comment: Regarding two versions of TexLive, I initially had that doubt. So, I completely removed all versions and files of TexLive from the system and reinstalled it.

Comment: This is strange. What does `which pdflatex` say in the terminal.

Comment: It says /usr/bin/pdflatex

Comment: Actually I found another Texlive folder in /usr/share. Going further into the folders, I found the folder tools which does not have mathtools.sty. I tried to copy this file from the mathtools folder in the /usr/local path, but the file is not being copied.

Comment: Let us check, is there also a bin dir in usr->local->texlive->2018->bin? If there is then you have two latex installations

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I found the bin dir in usr->local->texlive->2018->bin

Comment: Latex does not search the disk for files (only the folder where your ducument is), it takes too long. Here is what you do: first find the folder under path you mention above which has a latex program in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91623/discussion-between-jackt-and-daleif).

Comment: Go to that folder, run `pwd` and copy the result let us call it XXX. Run `cd` to go to your root. In a text editor, open `.profile` (note the dot). At the end add `export PATH=XXX:$PATH` note the colon. Save, then log out, and in again. Now run `which latex` it should now point to the latex under usr local and thus be able to find mathtools.